# Help me trying to understand transistor and vacuum tubes?

Tags: transistors, vacuum-tube

Obviously I'm a newbie in electronics and I think I understood how transistors and previously, vacuum tubes work (as a electrical switch, I'm disregarding amplifying in this question).

But for me is hard to see why people wanted to do that in the first place (please, don't be offended about my level nobbieness).

My point is, what is wrong with a manual switch? what would I want a electrical switch passing a small voltage to close a bigger voltage in the first place?

I've been studying a lot those weeks, I understand transistors are crucial for CPUs for the logic gates as well vacum tubes were back on the early TV days. But its been hard to connect the dots for me.

It feels the explanation is simple, I hope you can guide me through

Comment: you question has nothing to do with electronics actually .... by your own words, you do not understand why you would want to do something automatically, when you can do it manually. .... for example, why would you want to have automatic irrigation system when you can simply turn a valve with your hand.

Comment: @jsotola I don't understand why you think this has nothing to do with electronics. Are you saying transistor is an automatic switch? that's why I understand from your analogy

Comment: you said it yourself, `My point is, what is wrong with a manual switch? what would I want a electrical switch passing a small voltage to close a bigger voltage in the first place?` .... you are saying `why use a machine when you can do it manually`

Comment: Good luck trying to flip a billion switches in your computer! :) the reason why transistors exist is because we can simply send a (right amount of) voltage to the transistor to do it automatically.

Comment: Did you know that a smart phone has several hundred Billion transistors in it, some running in the GHZ range. Find another hobby.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it'll help to think concretely.

- You have a tiny voltage from an antenna, and want to turn it into music in your living room.  How can you do that? The sound can come from a loudspeaker, but that involves more power (more voltage, more current) than you can get from the antenna by a *very* large factor.

You shouldn't "disregarding amplifying". Fundamentally, that's what a transistor or tube is:  Something that can take a little signal, combine it with some energy, and make a much bigger signal that has more desirable characteristics.

There are lots of uses for that.

- You want to sense a small voltage from a humidity sensor, and use that to control much larger fan motor.
- You want to have an IR sensor watch your front door, and when it sees a person there, turn on the lights.  But the IR sensor only provides a millionth the power needed for the lights...

Comment: And also in pure logic switching. Otherwise one output would not be able to drive several inputs, which each drive an output which...

Answer (score 3):

Electrically controlled switches were taken into use when it appeared, that manual switching was too slow, too inaccurate, too dangerous, needed too much human work or it simply was not comfortable, because the place where the decision "should it be ON or OFF" was made, was different than the place of physical switching. That happened well before year 1900 and the solution was a relay.

Electronic switching components were taken into use as soon as they were available, because relays were too slow for many wanted applications or their life span was too short due the sheer amount of needed state transitions. For small currents relays appeared to be inefficient and needed too much space.

Answer (score 2):

> ...what is wrong with a manual switch? what would I want a electrical switch passing a small voltage to close a bigger voltage in the first place?

The remote control for my TV sends a coded burst of light by 
switching hundreds of times according to a rule that is different for each button.   I'm not dexterous enough to do that in a tenth of
a second.

The TV receives a small amount of light, converts it to electricity,
and amplifies it before decoding.  Then it applies another rule and switches volume,
or channel, or input source.     It would be very difficult
to put all of those switches into your hand.

The apparatus of a dial telephone network puts rooms full of 
switches to work making the connections according to the coded pulses
that the dial makes; a seven-digit local call ties up dozens of switches
at several telephone offices.   Manual telephone switchboards are
possible, but not economic.

So, there are advantages in speed, in size, in cost, to using an
electronic switch.   Or, using thousands of them.  Or millions.
The computer I type this on, has hundreds of millions of 'em in its CPU.

Answer (score 0):

During WW2, the British engineer Tommy Flowers used his prior experience with vacuum tubes in the British Post Office to develop a 5,000 tube combinatorial logic module for speed up of the code-breaking activities addressing the German military encrypted messages.

The compute power, from tapes reading in 10,000 characters per second, of the vacuum tubes was somewhere between 1Million and 10Million operatons per second, because of the parallelism that Tommy Flowers implemented.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Flowers